# How to Change Another Branch into Master Branch

Tags: git

I have some unwanted commits in `master` branch, I've made a branch say, `new_branch` from previous commit. Now `new_branch` Looks better than master, I'd like to change `new_branch` as my `master` branch How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locally, you can do

```
git checkout new_branch
git branch -D master
git checkout -b master
```

If `master` has been pushed somewhere, you can now do

```
git push --force WHEREVER master
```

But *watch out*, since this will require everyone who pulled the previous `master` to perform Git black magic to get the new `master`.

If `master` has been published, then it's better to just `git revert` the bad commits.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
git branch -m master oldmaster
git branch -m new_branch master
```

Note that you will have to use force push if you have pushed elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you haven't published `master` yet:

- `git reset --hard 'id of the last good commit in master'` to throw away the commits in master
- `git merge --ff-only new_branch` to apply the commits from `new_branch` to master.

Comment: Wouldn't just `git reset --hard new_branch` be better?